# External display color quality problem

Tags: drivers, graphics, multiple-monitors, display, intel

I have a Lenovo Edge E531 laptop with Intel HD Graphics 4000 running Ubuntu 19.10. I recently purchased an external monitor (LG 27MK400 ) to use with my laptop. When connected to laptop, the display turns yellowish as you can see:

[image: yellow tinted image on external monitor].

I tried this display with Window laptop and MacBook and did not have any problem. I think that I have a video driver problem and do not know how to try different video drivers made for Ubuntu.

Comment: I was able to resolve the problem by connecting monitor to laptop via HDMI cable.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not in changing drivers (since the Intel HD Graphics drivers are in the kernel), but instead in using a good HDMI cable.

Also, if you want to adjust the color profile of the external device, as noted in https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/color-calibrate-screen.html.en , tap the Super key (AKA 'Windows' key) and pick **Settings | Devices | Color** | Select your screen || and make the adjustments.